# It is good to use webservice types in view layer in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, architecture

I am starting new ASP.NET application with following architecture.

Controller get data from webservices and forward it to the view. Thew view just format the data. I see two approaches for this.

1) Controller loads data from webservice and forward it to the view. I don't like to much, because view is dependent on webservice. I mean because the view uses types from webservice.

2) controller read data from webservice and create new object and forward this new object (model) to view. This is better, because there is no dependency of view on webservice, but I don't like to repack every object queried from webservice.

What is your opinion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option n°2 is the best. Those new objects are called view models and are created to contain only data that the view need to display.
Yep, it will be annoying to map object from web service to your view model but it exists libraries like AutoMapper to help doing it more easily and quickly.

Comment: @qub1n yes, i mean this lib.